# Android How to test app power consumption when plugged

Tags: android, android-studio

How to test power consumption when plugged? I've try [Batterystats and Battery Historian](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/battery-historian.html) on Android Studio. It works fine when I unplugged the device for short time and plugged it later and I can get batterystats dumpsys. But when I consistently plugged the device, I still get batterystats dumpsys but missing a part of report called "Estimated power use"(Where I can find app power comsumption). And here comes my question: Is there anyway to get app power consumption when I consistently plugged the device?

Any help will be appreciated!

An example output of "Estimated power use":

> ```
> Uid u0a48: 0.0198 ( cpu=0.0140 wifi=0.00534 sensor=0.000373 )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use diagnostic tool : PowerTutor.Search in playstore and install use it . and if you need source codes of powertutor,here : https://github.com/msg555/PowerTutor

Comment: Thanks for answering I've searched power tutor before. Some of developers says its a little bit outdated for android6.0+ . I'll do more research on it. Thanks